# Rewrite formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have the formula:
$$ R(T)=R(T_0)e^{-B\left(\frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{1}{T}\right)} $$
How can I isolate $T$? 
I came this far:
$$ \ln\left(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0)}\right)= -B\left(\frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{1}{T}\right) \implies \frac{\ln\left(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0)}\right)}{-B}=\frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{1}{T}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the logarithm of both sides we obtain
$\ln\left(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0}\right)=-\frac{B}{T_0}+\frac{B}{T}$   and then
$\ln\left(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0}\right)+\frac{B}{T_0}=\frac{B}{T}$
solving for $T$ we get
$T=\frac{B}{\ln\left(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0}\right)+\frac{B}{T_0}}$

Comment: You have $T$ both in the right hand side and in the left hand side. I am assuming the OP was looking for a solution $T$ that solved the original equation.

Comment: but $R(T)$ is the given function and $T$ stands allone

Answer (score 4):

Now add $\frac 1T+\frac{ln(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0)})}{B}$ to each side, which gets $\frac 1T$ alone on the left.  Invert both sides

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{T}=\frac{1}{T_0}+\frac{\ln(\frac{R(T)}{R(T_0)})}{B} $$
How do I invert?

Comment: You can put the right over a common denominator $BT_0$.  Then you will have a single fraction on each side. You can just flip the fractions, which is the same as dividing them into $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If the function $f :x \mapsto R(x)e^{-B/x}$ is invertible (that depends on what is exactly $R(x)$), than you can rearrange the terms from your equation as
$$
f(T) = f(T_0)
$$
from which 
$$
T = f^{-1}(f(T_0)) = T_0
$$